# Chromebook arm64 Translations

Tags: arm-processors, chromebook

I am trying to run an application on a chromebook and this application only supports arm64. [Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/device-support) it says that arm64 has very poor translations. My chromebook is in developer mode and I was wondering if there is another way to provide chrome os with a complete set of arm64 translations.

Comment: Unfortunately the linked page does not describe why some Chromebooks support arm64 translation and others don't. But even if it is a restriction by the used software and not a hardware limitation we are talking about ChromeOS not a Linux or Windows system that can fully modify as you want. If your Chromebook does not support arm64 support I don't think there is much you can do about it.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the topicality of this question. On one hand, the question is about running Android app, but on the other hand, it's more of asking to modify Chrome OS, which is not about Android at all. Note that questions about Chrome OS may have more chance to be answered on [su] or [unix.se] (reference: [Are Android apps running on Chrome OS on topic?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2336/44325))